# What is the role of getInputStream() here?

Tags: java, httpurlconnection

I have a JSON object which I'm trying to write to the json file. I think the write() method of the OutputStreamWriter object is responsible for writing to the json file but if I don't add the last line "urlConnection.getInputStream();" the changes do not take effect. Please explain what this line is doing and why do I need it because as far as I know getInputStream() is used to read an input stream from the open connection not write to the open connection.

```
URL database_url = new URL("https://example.firebaseio.com/posts.json");

URLConnection urlConnection = database_url.openConnection();
urlConnection.setRequestProperty("X-Requested-With", "Curl");

urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);

OutputStreamWriter out = new OutputStreamWriter(urlConnection.getOutputStream());
out.write(obj.toJSONString());
out.close();

urlConnection.getInputStream();
```

Comment: Presumably the socket doesn't complete until you open both ends of it.

Comment: Nothing happens until you request some input, either by getting the inout or error stream or the status code. The output is being freed in memory so that Java can set the content length.

Comment: can you explain this in more detail?

Comment: I thought I already had.

Comment: Have you tried it *without* the call in question?  Does it have the effect that you want?  If not, go back and read the comment from EJP again a little more closely.

Comment: I'll type it again without the typos. Nothing happens until you request some input, either by getting the input or error stream or the status code. The output is being saved in memory so that Java can set the content length. And from the deleted answer, it opens the connection and sends the output. if those things haven't already happened.

Comment: @EJP okay but why nothing happens until the input request and what content length are talking about.

Comment: Nothing happens *because Java is saving the output in memory so it can set the content length,* and the content length I am talking about is the Content-length header of the request.

Comment: okay, got it. thank you for your time